# node-oidc-provider access token format

Tags: format, access-token, pkce, oidc-provider

I've setup oidc-provider for pkce (v7x). When I do the following:

1. request a code from /auth with response_type='code'
2. Used the code to get token form /token with grant_type=authorization_code
3. Receive token as shown:

```
{
access_token: "a8DM82TgXF-cjlzH8yOjuK6_OF9h_JaYJjSPrAdCRG0"
expires_in: 86400
id_token: "eyJhbGci....FQg"
scope: "openid"
token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

How can I get node-oidc-provider to return a JWT access_token with claims?

Answer (score 1):

You shall use the [Resource Indicators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8707.html) feature ([oidc-provider docs](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/docs/README.md#featuresresourceindicators)) and request an access token for a particular resource server, in the resource indicators feature the configuration `getResourceServerInfo` is for validating the resource indicator provided (or defaulted to) in the authorization request. The return value from this `getResourceServerInfo` helper also defines the access token format (`accessTokenFormat` property), when the value is `jwt` the resulting Access Token is, well, a JWT following the [JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9068.html).

Comment: Thank you, that helped allot! For some reason when I add the below to the Provider configuration, I didn't have to set the `accessTokenFormat` explicitly.
`formats: { AccessToken(token) { return 'jwt'; } }`

Comment: That's no longer the way to do so. Please follow my guidance and use the resource indicators feature to get the best overall results.

Comment: When I set `accessTokenFormat: 'jwt'` as you described, it results in the `id_token` being returned as a `jwt` but the `access_token` is still a reference token. Any idea why this is happening?